# How to convert Count to Boolean value after Group by

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Publisher and Book.Book has a Foreign Key on Publisher.I want to know if publishers have books.With SQL expression below,i can know how many books each publisher have.But how can i convert `Count(Book.uuid)` to a Boolean value?

```
select publisher.uuid, Count(Book.uuid)
from Publisher
left join Book
    on Publisher.uuid = Book.publisher_id
group by Publisher.uuid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    p.uuid,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(b.uuid) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS has_count
FROM Publisher p
LEFT JOIN Book b
    ON p.uuid = b.publisher_id
GROUP BY p.uuid;
```

If you want an actual boolean expression, then just compare the count directly to a value, e.g.

```
SELECT
    p.uuid,
    COUNT(b.uuid) > 0 AS has_count
FROM Publisher p
LEFT JOIN Book b
    ON p.uuid = b.publisher_id
GROUP BY p.uuid;
```